# Comparable Enum with Int

Tags: swift, enums

To compare enums which has an `Int` as the raw value I've added:

```
func  <<T: RawRepresentable>(a: T, b: T) -> Bool where T.RawValue: Comparable {
    return a.rawValue < b.rawValue
}
```

Now I can do:

```
enum Foo: Int {
    case a = 1
    case b = 2
}

let a = Foo.a
let b = Foo.b

print(a < b) // true
```

But how should I make it so I can compare enums like:

```
print(b < 1) // error
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need another `<` override where the operands are a RawRepresentable and an Int?

Comment: I've been trying but failed to do so. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just do more of what you're already doing:

```
func <<T:RawRepresentable>(a:T, b:Int) -> Bool where T.RawValue == Int {
    return a.rawValue < b
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more generic version of [@matt's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41350729/2976878) – which would allow you to compare a given `RawRepresentable` with its `RawValue`. Although note that you'll have to implement both overloads for both `<` & `>` in order to allow for all 4 possible combinations of comparisons.

```
func < <T : RawRepresentable>(lhs: T, rhs: T.RawValue) -> Bool where T.RawValue : Comparable {
    return lhs.rawValue < rhs
} // allows b < 1

func < <T : RawRepresentable>(lhs: T.RawValue, rhs: T) -> Bool where T.RawValue : Comparable {
    return lhs < rhs.rawValue
} // allows 1 < b

func > <T : RawRepresentable>(lhs: T, rhs: T.RawValue) -> Bool where T.RawValue : Comparable {
    return lhs.rawValue > rhs
} // allows b > 1

func > <T : RawRepresentable>(lhs: T.RawValue, rhs: T) -> Bool where T.RawValue : Comparable {
    return lhs > rhs.rawValue
} // allows 1 > b
```

Although that being said, I would be wary of using such overloads. It's not so bad being able to say such things as `b < 1`, but the waters get more murky when allowing you to say `b < c` where `c` is an `Int` – it begins to become slightly unclear what you're actually comparing (not to mention adding extra complexity to overload resolution).

Simply saying `print(b.rawValue < 1)` is both clear and concise, and is the way I'd write it.

Answer (score 1):

`Int` isn't `RawRepresentable`, so it can't be used with your `<` operator.

Here are two fixes:

1. Make 2 new `<` overloads:

   - `<<T: RawRepresentable>(a: T, b: Int)`
   - `<<T: RawRepresentable>(a: Int, b: T)`
2. Make `Int` conform to `RawRepresentable`, and rewrite your existing `<` overload to use two generic types, which can be compared iff they have the same `RawValue`, which is itself `Comparable`.

   ```
   extension Int: RawRepresentable {
       public init?(rawValue: Int) { self.init(rawValue) }
       public var rawValue: Int { return self }
   }

   func < <T: RawRepresentable, U: RawRepresentable>(a: T, b: U) -> Bool
       where T.RawValue: Comparable, T.RawValue == U.RawValue {
           return a.rawValue < b.rawValue
   }

   enum Foo: Int {
       case a = 1
       case b = 2
   }

   print(Foo.a < Foo.b)
   print(Foo.b < 1)
   ```

Comment: Been trying this, but I was missing step 2. Thanks!

Comment: @Hamish Ooo good point. This is why I should compile before posting. Let me play around with it :)

Comment: @Alexander Looks good – although note that it'll allow for the comparison `Foo.a < Bar.a` where `Bar` is `RawRepresentable` with an `Int` `RawValue`, which may or may not be desired. As I say in my answer, I'm not fully convinced that adding these kinds of overloads is a good idea in practice when we can just say `b.rawValue < 1` instead :)

Comment: @Hamish Yeah, I realized that. I wouldn't do any of this, to be honest. I'm not a fan of this sort of implicit behaviour. Also, defining a comparison for **all** `RawRepresentable` enums makes no sense. Imagine a `Card` enum. The ranking of the cards is totally dependant on the game you're playing